# Simple rich text view in cocoa-touch

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, core-text

I'm working on an iOS app in which I need to implement a basic text view with these requirements:

- Rich text

  - Font emphasis (bold, italics).
  - Inline images for hyperlink-like actions.
- Scrolling

  - Getting and setting the scroll offset (for remembering the previous scroll position).
- Text selection

  - Getting the selected text character range.
  - Scrolling the view when selecting text, if needed.

I believe I could achieve this with `UIWebView` but the problem with this is that it provides very little control and is somewhat slow and shows a blank screen while loading. I was wondering if this could be achieved with Core Text but regarding the text selection I'm not sure. I'm hoping to achieve as iOS-native behaviour as possible.

What I'd need is pretty much like Instapaper's text view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OmniGroup have done something like this by creating a text editor much like `UITextView` which draws the text using Core Text but also has all the editing features of `UITextView` as well as Rich text features from Core Text.

You can find it [here](https://github.com/omnigroup/OmniGroup/tree/master/Frameworks/OmniUI/iPad).

Comment: Sadly this might be the best solution, but having read the relevant code quickly through, there's a lot of overhead with this approach. I might settle for `UIWebView` with javascript hacks and such but I think I'll hang on to code I extracted from the framework.

Comment: I ended up using the OmniGroup's framework but finally decided to give up and simply use `UIWebView` with local HTML+Javascript as content. That is not as nice as custom control but the framework wasn't without issues.

Comment: That is what I have ended up using too!

Answer (score 0):

There are some answers about this in StackOverflow, for example: [Core text tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763757/core-text-tutorial)

However the best tutorial I ever read about Core Text in iOS is not listed in any answer I've found: [How to create a simple magazine app with core text](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4147/how-to-create-a-simple-magazine-app-with-core-text)

Please notice that CoreText is only available for iOS 3.2 or superior.

Comment: Thank you, but neither of those tutorials handle text selection or vertical scrolling. Any ideas on documents or tutorials for those?