# iOS // show html -> rich text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

What is the best way to show html -> rich text in iOS?

The problem is that some images from this text should be available offline, so I can't use a simple UIWebView.

Ideally I want to show just html with an ability to replace some special tags with other controls (UIImageView etc). I don't need to download this images from html. Both images and html will be downloaded with issues. Just need to manage the layout.

Core Text is not suitable, because to use it I'll need to parse this html manually. It should be a simpler way.
This has to be supported by iOS 6, so I can't use anything new from iOS 7.

I've seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797943/simple-rich-text-view-in-cocoa-touch). Doesn't look like this OmniGroup framework will work for me.

[RTLabel](https://github.com/honcheng/RTLabel) doesn't support everything, what I want to have.

[DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText) looks good, but it's not free (don't want to show their license text).

Maybe it's another cool fremework, which I didn't find yet?

Answer (score 0):

Have tryed 
https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString%2BHTML.h
This will simply give string out of html. It might not be exactly what you are looking for but hope this will solve part of your problem.

But this will not solve your offline image viewing. 
For image

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Will do a async download and cache image.

Comment: MWFeedParser - it's juts for feeds, isn't it? I'll have more complex html. SDWebImage - I don't need to download images from this html. I'll already have them downloaded separately with an issue.

Comment: NSString+HTML give u lots of html parsing option ... just thought it might be helpful to you as have a topic saying HTML to text. Yes SDwebImage is good if you have to download images form web once and store it as a Cache